# AND gate example

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic

When I closed switch 1, I apply 9 V to input 1 of the AND gate, but there is a resistor here.

Can I be sure that the total 9 volts does not drop through the resistor?

Why is the voltage dropped across the resistor?

[image]

The link of picture: http://sullystationtechnologies.com/icandgate.html

Comment: HC/High-speed C-MOS is not specified for 9 V, neither on inputs, nor as \$V_{cc}\$. See implementation note 5 of your hyperlink. (Another picture & schematic of unbuffered power to a digital IC.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *does* drop, but only a very small and thus negligible amount. The resistor is 10k, the resistance of a closed switch is almost zero, let's assume it is 1 Ohm. That means that the voltage drop across the resistor (compared to the open switch) will be in the order of 1/10000. Thus the voltage across the resistor will be 8.999 V and the voltage across the switch 0.001 V. Since the AND gate is a binary element, this is still clarly recognized as "High" level.

In fact, depending on the type of gate used, anything that is higher than 1/3 to 1/2 of VCC is considered a "High" level.

Comment: The OP means the voltage drop across the resistor while you are talking about the voltage drop across the contact. You have to clarify it.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Better now? Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand what you're referring to.

Comment: Does the input resistor of 74HC08 have no effect?

Comment: The problem is in the wording of the question, not in your answer, which is perfect.

Comment: @SerkanKaya These elements have a very high input impedance (=input resistance), so it's also negligible for most use cases. It's not infinite, but for most practical applications, you can assume it is.

Comment: @PMF Thank you so much.